# How to add JButtons next to each other without gap/space like in Windows Calculator?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, layout-manager

I'm making a calculator same as provided in windows 10 for practice purpose, but I am unable to remove the space between the `JButtons`. I'm using Netbeans designer view to do this. I have tried by doing margin as 0 even doing -2 of both the buttons but whenever I resize the button and drag it to the other one, the other button goes away automatically.

Here is the screen shot what I want to do:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBQhk.jpg]

Here is the design view:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwkoq.jpg]

Comment: You will likely need to change the button borders, as they tend to have their own insets defined by the look and feel

Comment: See also this [calculator example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).  It uses `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the expression in the text field. To change it to your stated requirement, edit `JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 2, 2));` to `JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4));`. See the documentation on grid layout for why that works.

Comment: *"i'm using Netbeans designer view to do this"* - Then don't, you won't learn anything by doing this

Comment: its not working in netbeans, whenever i add something through code it doesn't show up there (in the design view) Container keysPanel = getContentPane(); keysPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4,0,0)); nothing happens no effects

Comment: *"its not working in netbeans"* Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. Aside: I agree you should stop using Netbeans Designer View. Not only will you learn nothing, but I (for one) don't help people with 'D&D GUI designer' problems.

Answer (score 1):

1. Give the JPanel that holds the JButtons a GridLayout, one with proper rows and columns (call the constructor that uses 2 parameters, again for rows and columns) but that uses no more parameters -- so the layout's horizontal and vertical gap is set to the default size of 0. [GridLayout API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)
2. Add your JButtons to this JPanel.
3. Be sure to `pack()` the JFrame (or other top-level window) after adding components
4. And calling `setVisible(true)` after packing

That's really all there is to this.

Comment: not working in netbeans, whenever i add something through code it doesn't show up there (in the design view) Container keysPanel = getContentPane();
    keysPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4,0,0));

Comment: Don't use the netbeans form editor - it will just confuse the issue.  Start a new plain old project and hand code the UI, you will learn a significant amount more